9V Battery Supply power for Op Amp
I have some questions about some theory and design methods. I am currently trying to power op amp INA333 and multiplexer MUX506IPWR.
I have decided to use a 9V battery (I have to use battery), voltage divide it to a buffer for 0V ref so I can have a +-4.5V output then use a boost converter to step it up to 5V.
However I am concerned about battery life as boost converters will pull more current out of the battery reducing its life. I am also not sure about the effects of capacitive load of the op amp.
Another consideration I have is using a charge pump. However this would require more filtering of the output and would also have the same capacitive load issue.
Another consideration I have is using 2 9V battery, which would be the easiest method however it would be more ideal to have just a single battery.
Any thoughts on which method is better?

You can make a virtual ground. It's basically just a class-AB stage that drives the virtual ground. But it will be power-hungry. You will at least double (likely worse) the current draw on your battery to get it done. You may be able to find good ICs that take in a single supply (9 V) and are efficient switchers producing regulated split rails. I have not looked for them so would have to spend time I'd rather let you spend, looking. But I wouldn't be surprised to find some. The double 9 V battery solution is attractive, except as you suggest the +/-9 V exceeds allowed rails and so needs more.

There may also be power virtual ground ICs to look at, as well. Here's an example of a single to dual split supply switcher. That one will NOT accept +9 V as its source supply. But this is the kind of thing you may want to look for. It's current output level is around the right place, as well. Suppliers like Mouser and Digikey will have search engines to help. So will manufacturers like TI. Do some of your own searching, look over what you see, think about which of them rise to the top of your list, then re-ask here about comparing them, perhaps?

Do you really need split rails? You might be able to get by with a single-ended solutiion. But you provided no details of the application beyond "I want to power an opamp and a mux".

@MOSFET Yes due to the need for a 16 to 2 multiplexer which requires dual supply. Single supply multiplexers are typically single output.

@rel No thoughts, really. It's your call to be honest. I don't know enough about your situation. Dual split rail switcher ICs will be boutique and lock you in pretty tightly to a specific IC and supplier. A power virtual ground IC is perhaps a little better in that regard. Two 9 V batteries are just another complexity because the devices you want to operate can't run directly from 7.5 V to 9 V, which is what the 9 V batteries do for you as they get used up over time. I use a discrete design to split a 9 V battery into two matched rails. But it's a lot more parts. Just nothing boutique.

@periblepsis All the ICs that have been picked are for +-5V and 3.3V supply voltage. So even if the battery degraded to 7.5V, with a buck converter the output should stay stable at 5V. Are there any other complexities of 2 batteries I should worry about? I have 2 9V batteries in series and I am using VRA2415LD-15WR2.

@rel I still think it's entirely your call. You are right about bucks doing just fine with a 9 V battery (or two.) So that's another path that works. Even if you couldn't depend on the buck method (which you could in the two-9 V battery case) you could use buck-boost devices. So it's not a barrier. Just keep in mind the limited current compliance of 9 V batteries and the fact that they have a significant series resistance which is 1 or 2 Ohms even when fresh (gets worse as they get used up.)
